# Parsing unusual Json using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: .net, json

Here's an unusual json I'm getting from a web service.

```
{"SearchResults":[{"PageCount":"1"},
{"SEARCHVAL":"Result","CATEGORY":"Category1","X":"1","Y":"2"},
{"SEARCHVAL":"AnotherResult","CATEGORY":"Category1","X":"2","Y":"2"}]}
```

I'd like to get only the Searchval's, categories, and x's and y's and skip the pagecount. How do I skip the seachresults without using a third-party library. Does .Net have something as flexible as Silverlight's System.Json to parse this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JavaScriptSerializer's Deserialize and put the result into a Dictionary.

The code gets lengthier because of the extra lines needed to make you way to the data by casting the objects into ArrayList and Dictionary over and over.

Json.NET is alot easier and better to use but it is possible to use JavaScriptSerializer without defining classes and end up with an 'OK' job of parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). You could also use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) but that will require you to map out the whole object I think. Judging by [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `System.Json` will probably maybe make it into .NET 4.5 (whenever that will be released).

Comment: since i wan to do it without a 3rd party library, json.net is not an option. I'm doing this on .net 3.5 so the System.Json for non SL projects is excluded on this too. I'm new on using JavaScriptSerializer and since this is a weird Json structure, could you point me to an example that deals with something similar as this?